# Error whenever trying to insert list of records into VisualForce Page from custom controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, code

I currently have a visualforce page with a custom controller that counts the amount of records that has a field marked as a specific status from a picklist. I need to be able to display those records in a list format on the visual force page as well and have a real time timer that counts up from the second the record is registered on the page, but I always get an error whenever I try to insert the list into my VF page, any help would be appreciated. Also, if anyone knows how to implement what I am trying to achieve then that would be MUCH appreciated, here is my current code.

**VF PAGE**

```
 <apex:page controller="LeadAlertController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>
    <style>
    td{
        border: 1px ;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    </style>
    <table align="center" style="width:100%;border:1px solid">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <h3>Number of Hot Leads</h3>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <h3>Number of Hot Leads Over 10 Minutes</h3>
            </td>
             <td align="center">
                <h3>List of Names</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <h1>{!Leads}</h1>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <h1>{!OverLeads}</h1>
            </td>
             <td align="center">
                <h1>{!Names}</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(OverLeads>0,true,false)}">
        <audio src="/resource/alert" type="audio/mp3" autoPlay="true">
        </audio>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

**CUSTOM CONTROLLER CODE**

```
   public without sharing class LeadAlertController {
    public integer leads {get;set;}
    public integer overleads {get;set;}
    public List<lead__c> Names {get;set;}




    public LeadAlertController() {
        leads = [select count() from lead__c where lead_status__c=:'Not Attempted'];
        overleads=[select count() from lead__c where lead_status__c=:'Not Attempted' AND x10MinAlert__c=:true];
        Names = [select Patient_Name__c from lead__c where lead_status__c=:'Not Attempted'];


    }
}
```

**Whenever I try to insert "Names into the VF page, I get "visualforce Error: Unknown property LeadAlertController.Names" as an error.**

Comment: How are you using Names attribute in visualforce page? I cannot see it in your visualforce page

Comment: I just edited the post to show where I put it, I actually got it to work somehow I'm not sure how, I didn't change anything. Now it's just displaying the ID but I need it to display the field "patient_name__c", do you know how to fix that?

Comment: you have to use a datatable, pageblocktable or repeat to iterate through a collection (`{!names}`)